# The values selected in multiselect box should be displayed in the same page without clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, html, multi-select

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Get Selected Values</title>
<script>
    function listboxresult() {
    var spanresult = document.getElementById("result1");
    spanresult.value = "";
    var x = document.getElementById("sel");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
        if (x.options[i].selected == true) {
            spanresult.value += x.options[i].value + " ";
            document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = spanresult.value;
            
        }
    }   
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Select fav color</h2>
    <select name="sel" id="sel" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option> 
        <option value="Black">Black</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="White">White</option>
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="Green">Green</option>               
    </select>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <br>
    <div> 
    <input type="button" id="but1" value="Click" onclick="listboxresult();">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="result1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to display the values on the same page by clicking on the value but not by clicking the submit button. My code works with the submit button, but I should not use it to display the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the button and add an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on the `select` field, listening on the `change` event.

Whenever, the selection is changed, just call your existing function as is to set the result in the `div`.

In this first version, if multiple options are selected, then the order of the options follows the order of the options in the `select`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Get Selected Values</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Select fav color</h2>
    <select name="sel" id="sel" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option> 
        <option value="Black">Black</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="White">White</option>
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="Green">Green</option>               
    </select>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="result1"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("sel").addEventListener("change", () => {
            /* Your function verbatim */
            const spanresult = document.getElementById("result1");
            spanresult.value = "";
            const x = document.getElementById("sel");
            for (let i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
                if (x.options[i].selected == true) {
                    spanresult.value += x.options[i].value + " ";
                    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = spanresult.value;
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this second version, the order of the options shown depends on the order in which they were selected. This is achieved by maintaining an array of selected options -- pushing new selected options onto the array, and removing any deselected options.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Get Selected Values</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Select fav color</h2>
    <select name="sel" id="sel" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option> 
        <option value="Black">Black</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="White">White</option>
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="Green">Green</option>               
    </select>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="result1"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        /* Maintain an array of selected options */
        let selected = [];

        const select = document.getElementById("sel");
        document.getElementById("sel").addEventListener("change", () => {
            for (const option of select.options) {
                if (option.selected === true) {
                    /* For each selected option... */
                    if (!selected.includes(option.value)) {
                        /* Only add it to the array of selected values once */
                        selected.push(option.value)
                    }
                } else {
                    /* Otherwise, remove it from the array of selected options */
                    selected = selected.filter(e => e !== option.value);
                }
            }
            /* Write the selected options once they are all known */
            document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = selected.join(" ");
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in the above code when I select the colors randomly for display it gets sorted. but my requirement is it should be displayed on the order I click. kindly help

Comment: @silvanus I'm not sure what you mean about the order. When you make a selection, the `result1` `div` gets updated. This seems to fit your original question. If you desire something different, you'll have to [edit] the question to provide more details about the intended behavior.

Comment: consider this scenario: I click Black first Black is displayed. while pressing the control button I select white, here black and white are displayed. again while pressing the control button i select red. The output is displayed as Black Red White but i need the output as Black White Red.

Comment: @silvanus makes sense, in the case of preserving the selection order of multiple selected options, you can use an array to keep track of the options. I've updated my answer with a 2nd version that does this.